# How do I properly do two events on one control when they depend on one another's changes?

Tags: jquery

Is there a proper way/design for doing this? or must I combine them into one function/event and base them off the values returned from the Ajax?

I have a dropdownlist with two Change Events/Functions like so,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlFacilityDatabases").change(UpdateCategoriesList).change(UpdateReportsList);
}
```

Both functions modify options on "#ddlCategories" and "#ddlReports".
UpdateCategoriesList() modifies my "#ddlCategories" Options and UpdateReportsList() modifies my "#ddlReports" Options.

Here is one of my Functions (Only posting one since they're nearly Identical, just changes a couple locations and names)

```
function UpdateCategoriesList() {

    // Disable the Dropdown.
    $("#ddlCategories").attr("disabled", true);

    // Get Selection Value.
    var Selection = {
        "FacilityDatabaseName": $("#ddlFacilityDatabases").val()
    };

    // Send JSON to /Select/getCategories/.
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Select/getCategories/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        data: Selection,
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Parse Array.
            var Categories = JSON.parse(response).categories;

            // Clear Categories DropDownList.
            $("#ddlCategories").children("option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() != "") {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });

            // Add New Categories.
            var length = Categories.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (Categories[i] != null || Categories[i] != "") {
                    $("#ddlCategories").append("<option value=\"" + Categories[i] + "\">" + Categories[i] + "</option>");
                }
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            // re-enable dropdownlist
            $("#ddlCategories").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
}
```

The Problem is when I add them both to the event handler like above it runs them but the page updates the dropdownlists after both the functions run. I need the first one to update the page then the second one to do so since the second is dependent on the first's changes.

Comment: BTW: $("#ddlCategories").attr("disabled", false); should be: $("#ddlCategories").removeAttr("disabled"); "disabled" is not a true/false attribute.

Comment: @Diodeus it is if you use `.prop` :-D

Comment: This is true. Strangely I've never seen anyone actually use .prop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you want to impose an ordering on asynchronous calls. If `UpdateReportsList` must come after `UpdateCategoriesList`, then you have two options.

Option 1: as Neal pointed out, call the second function from within the ajax call of the first.

Option 2: make both calls blocking, instead of asynchronous, like this:

```
$.ajax(
    url: ...,
    async: false,
    ...
);
```

then call

```
$("#ddlFacilityDatabases").change(function (){
    UpdateCategoriesList();
    UpdateReportsList();
});
```

Overall, I think the first option is better, if you can change those two functions.

Comment: @Neal What kind of issues? I've never had any issues when I used jQuery functions.

Comment: Turning off asynch? if the server process hangs, the page **will hang**!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the second function to the AJAX callback of the 1st function and it will run in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use-case for [`$.Deferreds`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

```
function UpdateCategoriesList() {
    var deferred = $.Deferreds();
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function() {
            // ...
            // Resolve the deferred once all operations are done
            deferred.resolve();
        }   
    });

    // Make sure you return the deferred
    return deferred;
}
```

This allows you to do the following:

```
$("#ddlFacilityDatabases").change(function (){
    // When the deferred is resolved, it will call UpdateReportsList
    UpdateCategoriesList().done(UpdateReportsList);
});
```